# Show popup menu on `ActionBar` item click

Tags: android, android-actionbar, popupmenu

I have an `ActionBar` with an action item on it. After clicking on the action item, I want to show a popup menu.
I implemented this method, but I want to anchor it to the action item or to the `ActionBar`, not to any view from layout. How to get some kind of view to anchor it from `MenuItem`?

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, ??????); // What view goes here?
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.counters_overflow);
    popupMenu.show();
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621070/get-context-of-popupmenu-like-contextmenu

Answer (score 127, accepted):

So finally I found solution. When you want to anchor popupmenu to ActionItem in ActionBar you need to find view that renders ActionItem. 
Simple find view with findViewById() where id is same as id of your menu item in xml.

DISPLAYING POPUP:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // ...

    View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow); // SAME ID AS MENU ID
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); 
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.counters_overflow);
    // ...
    popupMenu.show();
    // ...
    return true;
}
```

MENU:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     ....

     <item
    android:id="@+id/menu_overflow"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_overflow"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/menu_overflow"/>

     ....

</menu>
```

If menu item is not visible (is in overflow) it does not work. findViewById returns null so you have to check for this situation and anchor to another view.

Comment: findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow) gives me a null view

Comment: findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow) gives null if you find in not activity root view. use Activity.findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow) and everything ok =))

Comment: is it possible to add a divider between specific items in the popupMenu ?

Comment: I get this error: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor

Comment: Perfect solution Thanks!

Comment: Not working. Getting cannot be used without an anchor error

Comment: If menu item is not visible (i. e. null), you can use the toolbar view instead and set gravity as Gravity.END, in that case it will be anchored to the overflow menu:
setDropDownGravity(Gravity.END);
setAnchorView(toolbarView);
Remember that anchor view must not be null, otherwise the app will crash when show() is called.

Comment: on kotlin it work like this: val menuItemView = findViewById<View>(R.id. menu_overflow)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me, so I found the problem by trial and error.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    View menuItemView = findViewById(item.getItemId()); 
    showPopupMenu(menuItemView)

    return true;
}

private void showPopupMenu(View anchor)
{
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, anchor);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```

The key here is that, the `item` in `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` must be shown on ActionBar. If the `item` is one of the items that appear when you press the 3 vertical dots on top right of ActionBar, then your app will crash.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

plz try this ..

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    String str=item.getTitle().toString(); 
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG). show();

    View view=findViewById(item.getItemId()); 
    switch(view.getId()){
        case Menu.FIRST:
            showPopup(view); // calling method
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}   

// custom method
private void showPopup(final View view) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, 0, Menu.NONE, "Item 1");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, 1, Menu.NONE, "Item 2");
    popupMenu.getMenu().add(0, 2, Menu.NONE, "Item 3");
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), item.getTitle() + "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Accepted Answer, the issue of re-inflating the popup on each call to onOptionsItemSelected() method can be simplified by doing it only once and just showing it as many times as we want.
(this works even for custom toolbar inflated via Menu Layout Inflater at runtime. Just keep in mind that the findViewById() to get the Menu item's view can return non-null value only when the view is actually present on the screen, ie, should be visible on the toolbar/actionbar.

**Note**: If the view is preset in the overflow menu of toolbar/actionBar there might be a chance that the view might get inflated only after the overflow menu was invoked at least once - using 3 dots?)

```
public class SomeActivity{
    
    private PopupMenu popup;
    .... // some code of the activity

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int menuItem = item.getItemId();
        switch (menuItem) {
            case R.id.tb_menu_plus:
                View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.tb_menu_plus);
                if(popup == null) {
                    popup = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
                    popup.inflate(R.menu.dropdown_popup_menu);
                }
                popup.show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the menu to be gone when you click specific item `return false` on that item.

```
        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.itemShare_:
                onShareClicked();
                return true;    // the menu will be gone
            case R.id.itemCopy_:
                onCopyClicked();
                return true;    // the menu will be gone
            case R.id.itemSelectAll_:
                onSelectAllClicked();
                return false;   // the menu will stay

               // ...
       }
```

Answer (score -5):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final View addView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add, null);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Add a Word").setView(addView)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            addWord((TextView) addView.findViewById(R.id.title));
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
```

get full source form here..

http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-action-bar-tab-menu-example

Comment: Sorry I do want to find right usage for PopupMenu created when ActionItem clicked. No workarounds.

Comment: The question is about PopupMenu and not AlertDialog.