# Show PopupMenu for MenuItem which is not an Action

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, popupmenu

how can I get the View Anchor for a PopupMenu if the corresponding MenuItem in ActionView is not shown as Action:

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.myMenu) {
        PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu (this, findViewById(R.id.myMenu));
        popupMenu.show();
        return true;
    }

    <item
        android:id="@+id/myMenu"
        appcompat:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/sharePage"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_share"/>
```

If `appcompat:showAsAction="always"` 
 everything works fine, but with   
         `appcompat:showAsAction="never"` the Method `findViewById(R.id.myMenu)` returns null.

Comment: remove that `appcompat:showAsAction="never"`

Comment: But what if I don't want it to show as action?

Comment: can you elaborate more what exactly your trying to say . All i know is  a popupmenu have an anchor view and if anchor view or action is not visible then the popup menu will not be shown

Comment: I'm trying to open a PopupMenu from an non-Action View, so basically with the Menu-Button (the three dots) as Anchor.

Comment: ohh !! so your using action bar or not, cause action bar has default overflow menu in which it will open your popup menu automatically ? tell?

Comment: Yeah i know that, but I have my own PopupMenu which should be opened after clicking on one item of ActionBars popupmenu (submenu)

Comment: What about to put a group into the MenuItem in xml? It might be a way to customize it later, I guess.

Comment: Look at this answer: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729592/show-popup-menu-on-actionbar-item-click)

Comment: I solved it with SubMenu.