# Popup menu on click of action bar Icon

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, popupmenu

I am trying to display a Popup menu on the click of an action bar Icon.
The problem is that I get a forced close of the app and the Popup menu does not display. What is wrong with my code? Thank you for your help.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_action, menu);

        return true;
    }


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ItemSelected = " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             case R.id.action_sort:
             showPopup(item.getActionView());
     }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "showPopup = " + popup, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
    }
```

menu_action.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".FileManagerActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_sort" android:title="@string/action_sort" android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_help" android:title="@string/action_help"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

popup_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"
        android:title="Change Picture" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fast_forward"
        android:title="Change Password" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/opt3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fast_rewind"
        android:title="Sign Out" />
</menu>
```

Logcat:

```
02-28 13:04:45.353  18838-18838/com.test.audio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.audio, PID: 18838
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.show(MenuPopupHelper.java:126)
            at android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu.show(PopupMenu.java:193)
            at com.test.audio.TouchActivity.showPopup(TouchActivity.java:5340)
            at com.test.audio.TouchActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(TouchActivity.java:5270)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1133)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
            at android.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:141)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: @Fazel I revised my code per you post, and added this: public void showPopup(View v) { View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.action_sort); and this code: popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu); When I run the app it gives a forced close with this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't pass MenuItem as View cause it s not.
so it s better to cast it as view like this

```
View menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.menu_overflow); // SAME ID AS MENU ID
PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView); 
popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.counters_overflow);
// And define click listener here.
popupMenu.show();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729592/show-popup-menu-on-actionbar-item-click)

Comment: with the code you recommended now I am getting this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 6. Any ideas on how to correct this error?

Comment: @user2308699 it s nothing to do with that code you check lib or imports you have used check this same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595187/android-xml-runtimeexception-failed-to-resolve-attribute-at-index-6

Comment: Thanks for the code to display a PopupMenu. It was step toward solving the problem I was having.