# Opening Popup menu instead of default action bar menu

Tags: android, popup, android-actionbar, popupmenu

Since I can't prevent default action bar menu from closing after selecting an item, I thought of using a popupmenu instead.
I want to use my popup menu with the same layout of the android action bar menu, so here's my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<group android:id="@+id/grp_filtro_selezione" android:checkableBehavior="all">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_all"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/all_menu"
        android:checked="true"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_aule"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/aule_menu"
        android:checked="false"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_aule_studio"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/aule_studio_menu"
        android:checked="false"/>
</group>
</menu>
```

I can't figure out how I can use my popup menu with something like this:

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
 popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pop_up, popup.getMenu());
```

and disabling the default action bar menu.

I think I should use the onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);

}
```

but how can I inflate my popup menu?

**EDIT:**

I almost found the solution but I have one problem. So, what i did is in the onCreateOptionsMenu I inflated a menu that includes only the action bar icons:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.prova_menu, menu);
}
```

And in the onOptionsItemSelected I tried this:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            View menuItemView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.settings); 
            popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), menuItemView);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.prova2);
            popupMenu.show();
}
```

It works fine, but there is a problem. The popup menu that I am showing has selectable items. When I click the icon to open the menu again all the items get reset probably because I inflate the menu layout everytime I show the popup menu.
I tried inflating the popup menu only one time in the onCreateOptionsMenu but I get this error when I call popupMenu.show().

```
 MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you most likely use `onCreateOptionsMenu` instead of `onCreateContextMenu`.

Have a look at the [API description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)) or the [Training Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus) on Menus

Comment: yes I know that, but I don't know how I can inflate the popup menu instead the default one

Comment: simply dont do anything in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and move the code to `onCreateContextMenu`. Use the View there to attach the popup. It's all described in the Training Guide

Comment: How can I attach it to the action bar icons if they don't show after i delete everything from the onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: U use a custom Toolbar in your layout, inflate the Menu Items (maybe use`onCreateOptionsMenu` for that), and find them by id inside the toolbar. But in `onOptionItemselected` you trigger your Popup

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing call to popup.show()?

Comment: @MarcoRipamonti if you are inflating toolbar menu then initialise your popup menu inside onOptionsItemSelected method. Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729592/show-popup-menu-on-actionbar-item-click

Comment: @MarcoRipamonti Does your prova2 menu file consists android:showAsAction="always" in it??